# How to pass in graphics g

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a nullpointerexeption when i try this code

```
package computerscience;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Recursion extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public Recursion() {
        setTitle("recursion");
        setSize(600, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void repeatSquare(Graphics g, double x, double y, double size, int count, int times) {

        if (count < times)
        {
            count++;
            double doublex = x - size/2;
            double doubley = y - size/2;
            double scale = 2.2;
            int intsize = (int) Math.round(size);
            int intx = (int) Math.round(doublex);
            int inty = (int) Math.round(doubley);
            try {
                g.drawRect(intx, inty, intsize, intsize);
//              DrawSquare(null, x - size/2, y - size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x - size/2, y + size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x + size/2, y - size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x + size/2, y + size/2, size/scale, count, times);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Program is finished! ");        
    }


    public static void main(String[] agrs)
    {
        Recursion r = new Recursion();
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times would you like to repeat the pattern: ");
        int times = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.next());
        r.repeatSquare( null, 600/2, 300/2, 100.0f, 0, times);
    }
}
```

The problem is at the line where it says:

```
g.drawRect(intx, inty, insize, intsize);
```

i know that you cant call drawrect to a null object but every tutorial i watch passes in null so i dont know why i am getting this problem and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your own code is passing `null` to `repeatSquare`... I find it unlikely that tutorials do that as well, as that would mean the code of those tutorials doesn't work either,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to pass in graphics g

You don't.

Swing will pass the `Graphics` object to the painting method of the component when Swing determines the component needs to be painted.

So you need to override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a `JPanel` with your custom painting. Then you add the panel to the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1):

You will never create a Graphics object. This is AWT concern, not yours. To do customized drawings, you'll need to overwrite the `paint` (for JFrame, for example) or the `paintComponent` (for JPanel, for example) method and there you do what you want if the Graphics Object. Your code should look like something like this:

```
package computerscience;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Recursion extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int times;

    public Recursion() {
        setTitle( "recursion" );
        setSize( 600, 300 );
        setVisible( true );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }

    public void repeatSquare( Graphics g, double x, double y, double size, int count, int times ) {

        if ( count < times ) {
            count++;
            double doublex = x - size / 2;
            double doubley = y - size / 2;
            double scale = 2.2;
            int intsize = (int) Math.round( size );
            int intx = (int) Math.round( doublex );
            int inty = (int) Math.round( doubley );
            try {
                g.drawRect( intx, inty, intsize, intsize );
//              DrawSquare(null, x - size/2, y - size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x - size/2, y + size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x + size/2, y - size/2, size/scale, count, times);
//              DrawSquare(null, x + size/2, y + size/2, size/scale, count, times);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                System.out.println( e );
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println( "Program is finished! " );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        super.paint( g );
        repeatSquare( g, 600 / 2, 300 / 2, 100.0f, 0, times );
    }

    public void setTimes( int times ) {
        this.times = times;
    }

    public static void main( String[] agrs ) {
        Recursion r = new Recursion();
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "How many times would you like to repeat the pattern: " );
        int times = Integer.parseInt( myScanner.next() );
        r.setTimes( times );
        r.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :) really helped and i upvoted